# How to find whether my assembly is a .NET component or a COM component?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, com

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to check if a DLL file is a CLR assembly in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366503/best-way-to-check-if-a-dll-file-is-a-clr-assembly-in-c-sharp)

I have a assembly from a DLL file.  I need to check whether the DLL file is originally from a .NET project or from a COM project.  How can I find it using C# programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it good enough to know if the assembly can be successfully loaded by the runtime?
If so, check out this question:

[Best way to check if a DLL file is a CLR assembly in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366503/best-way-to-check-if-a-dll-file-is-a-clr-assembly-in-c-sharp)

The problem is, as I said in my other answer, it's entirely possible that it could be both, if there's a COM wrapper for a .Net object in use. Read: Your question doesn't make sense.

It would make sense to ask: Is it native, or CLR? 
Or to ask: Does it support COM?

Comment: Yes, I am not clear of what I asked.  I lack knowledge in DLL, COM and C#.  Let me make the problem clear.

Comment: The dll file could be either created from a Smart Device C# or Smart Device C++ project.  How do I differentiate from these two DLLs.