How to detect if a Windows PE executable is for native code vs managed code?
I've been analysing Windows PE executables' binary file format.
I know how to differentiate PE32 (32 bit) vs PE32+ (64 bit) and how to differentiate x86 vs x64.
But I know that managed code uses the same PE executable format (.NET, C#, Mono, CLR, assembly etc) and I believe is documented to always set the architecture to "x86".
So what do I examine in the PE file to see if it's for native code or managed code?
I tried Looking at binary PE files, looking at official documentation and various blogs and repos. I didn't yet find what fields to look at. I may have missed it somewhere.
NOTE: I'm doing this programmatically on my Mac and don't currently have a working Windows machine. I'm looking for a programmatic answer so I can write my own analyser, not looking for a tool to analyse some PE files for me. In fact I can't run such tools if they're Windows apps.

This looks like a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/29643803/495455 - it'll be in the ECMA Specifications Partition II – Metadata which is shipped along with .NET SDK

@JeremyThompson I think you're right but I haven't been able to grok anything from that thread well enough to turn into code yet.


check first u16 of "Optional Header", which starts at offset 0x18 of the "PE Header". 0x10b means "PE32", 0x020b means "PE32+". 2. The "CLR Runtime Header" is in the "Optional Header" at offset 0xd0 for a "PE32" vs 0xe0 for a "PE32+". 3. The first u32 of the "CLR Runtime Header" is the "Virtual Address" and the second u32 is the "Size" (This is an "IMAGE DATA DIRECTORY". If both fields are 0 then there is no CLR managed code in this PE file.


The following may be of interest: Where is CorFlags.exe?

@user246821: Hehe hoping to install it on my old Intel Mac but that's a whole other can of worms. Just getting macOS on it to start with is a pain so far...

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1366517/10024425

@user246821: Yes that was the first/best help I found but wasn't sufficient on its own. It's a bit hard to decipher and only works on 32-bit PE32's, not on 64-bit PE32+'s.  But it is one of the resources I used to get to my solution in my comment above.

A PE file should be able to contain both native code and managed code. You can use PEReader to detect that. If HasMetadata is true, it means that the file contains managed code.
using var fs = File.OpenRead(FILEPATH);
using var reader = new PEReader(fs);
Console.WriteLine(reader.HasMetadata);

The field you want to look at is called CLR Runtime Header
