# C#: How to tell if an object is of a custom class or native type /.NET class?

Tags: c#, .net, class, types

I have this class

```
public class MyViewModel {
  public MyClass Thing { get; set; }
  public int Id { get { return Thing.Id; } }
  public string Name { get { return Thing.Name; } }
}
```

I noticed when I bind it to an ASP.NET GridView, it automatically omits `Thing`, and for a good reason (ie. because otherwise it will only show the meaningless "MyNamespace.MyClass" in all rows)

I am trying to do a similar thing in this method.

```
public static string ConvertToCsv<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
  foreach (T item in items)
  {
    if(item is not a native/.NET class) // <-- How do you do this?
      continue;
    else // If it is a string/int/bool/DateTime or something meaningful
    {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine whether a DLL is a managed assembly or native (prevent loading a native dll)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367761/how-to-determine-whether-a-dll-is-a-managed-assembly-or-native-prevent-loading) - check the highest scoring answer

Comment: Thanks Jeremy but I am not talking about files or DLL

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not sure about performance, but you could use somthing along the lines of

```
if(item.GetType().Namespace.StartsWith("System")) 
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Or filter before looping

```
public static string ConvertToCsv<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    foreach (T item in items.Where(i => i.GetType().Namespace.StartsWith("System")))
    {

    }
}
```

**Edit:** after a quick test the method above has some flaws, If your object is nullable (MyViewModel?) it will be picked up in this check (`System.Nullable<MyViewModel>`).

So perhaps you could use:

```
public static string ConvertToCsv<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    foreach (T item in items.Where(i => i.GetType().Module.ScopeName.Equals("CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary")))
    {

    }
}
```

**Another edit:**
There seems to be some issue with the last method also, But this one below is by far the fastest and most reliable, We just create a list of the System.Objects from the Assembly, and check if your item object is in that list.

```
private List<Type> _systemTypes;
public List<Type> SystemTypes
{
    get
    {
        if (_systemTypes == null)
        {
            _systemTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType().Module.Assembly.GetExportedTypes().ToList();
        }
        return _systemTypes;
    }
}

public static string ConvertToCsv<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    foreach (T item in items.Where(i => SystemTypes.Contains(i.GetType())))
    {
         // is system type
    }
}
```

Comment: Your latter is more elegant imo

Comment: Why not store only the namespaces? It could get even faster. Great sample though.

Comment: `typeof(Assembly)` instead of `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType().Module` seems more elegant and does the same.

Full line would be `_systemTypes = typeof(Assembly).Assembly.GetExportedTypes().ToList();` More than that it is more clear which Type is used for targeting here. Can be easily used for peeking at other assemblies besides mscorlib.

Comment: Besides, I would suggest using a HashSet instead of the List for performance reasons in case the checking is done many times.

Comment: I have to mention that both your and mine `_systemTypes` lists are not OK if the context is UWP + .NET native. For that you would need a different targeting type like this:
_systemTypes = typeof(string).Assembly.GetExportedTypes().ToList();

Comment: Is there any cases where typeof(Assembly) might become an issue? Could this reference some assembly we might not be suspecting? Also, does anyone know the performance issues using this method instead of just if statements to check the objects?

Comment: Note that `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType().Module.Assembly.GetExportedTypes()` will not include nullable versions of system types (such as `bool?`)

Comment: After further development, you can use `SystemTypes.Contains(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(i.GetType()))` to account for nullable system types such as `bool?`

Answer (score 0):

You would have to look it up in a predefined hash table or dictionary ... say by enumerating all the assemblies that are part of the .NET Framework SDK and storing the fully qualified name in a dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old but I think you are looking for Method.

```
Type type = result.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    string prs = property.GetMethod.ToString();
    if(!prs.StartsWith("System"))
    {
        //IS CLass
    } else {
       Console.WriteLine(property.Name + ":::" + property.Value);
    }
}
```