# How can I programmatically determine if a DLL is managed or unmanaged?

Tags: .net, managed

How can I, in a program, determine if a DLL is managed or unmanaged code? We're using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591557/how-to-tell-if-a-net-assembly-was-compiled-as-x86-x64-or-any-cpu?rq=1) to make sure all of our managed DLLs are MSIL. But it throws an exception on unmanaged DLLs so I need a way to first check if a DLL is managed.

Comment: How often are you doing it? Sometimes you just need to handle the exception and move on, I don't know if there is a easy (exceptionless) way to solve this.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It's in the build process so not a big time hit. I just dislike having exceptions when code is running as expected.

Comment: @DavidThielen There are ways to do it, but it's a bit complicated, since there's no direct API.  Personally, catching the exception is that approach I'd take, since it's just easy and cleaner...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine whether a DLL is a managed assembly or native (prevent loading a native dll)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367761/how-to-determine-whether-a-dll-is-a-managed-assembly-or-native-prevent-loading)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest option would most likely be to just try to open the file as you are, and catching the exception.  Any unmanaged assembly will throw an exception on `Assembly.LoadFrom`.

However, if you want to determine this more rigorously, you'd need to examine the PE header for the appropriate information yourself.  This [article describes the process](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kstanton/archive/2004/03/31/105060.aspx) in detail, but it requires checking the [IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure of the PE header of the DLL.

Comment: They sure don't make that easy do they :) Thank you

Comment: @DavidThielen No - unfortunately, there's no simple API for this, even in the native side.

Comment: @DavidThielen before you go off coding a way to do this, think about the times involved. If handling the exception adds maybe 2ms to the build time instead of writing out a way to parsing the PE header just do a little math if `(Time involved to write the handler / Time difference between exception handling and detecting) < Number of builds in the lifetime of the program` its not worth doing.